# branch.io Share Sheet message

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, branch.io

This is a function im calling on Ionic

```
regularShare(){
    // only canonicalIdentifier is required
    var properties = {
        canonicalIdentifier: 'content/' + this.itemId
    }

    // create a branchUniversalObj variable to reference with other Branch methods
    var branchUniversalObj = null
    Branch.createBranchUniversalObject(properties).then(function (res) {
        branchUniversalObj = res

        // optional fields
        var analytics = {

        }

        // optional fields
        var properties = {

        }

        var message = 'Check out this link'

        // optional listeners (must be called before showShareSheet)
        branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetLaunched(function (res) {
            // android only
            console.log(res)
        })
        branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetDismissed(function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        })
        branchUniversalObj.onLinkShareResponse(function (res) {
            console.log(res)
        })
        branchUniversalObj.onChannelSelected(function (res) {
            // android only
            console.log(res)
        })

        // share sheet
        branchUniversalObj.showShareSheet(analytics, properties, message)
    });
}
```

When I change var message to the following, it errors out. Error below.

```
var message = "Check out " + this.itemDetails.name + " (" + this.itemDetails.subcat+ ") in " + this.itemDetails.location + "."+ " Address: " + this.itemDetails.address+ ". Contact: " + this.itemDetails.phone
```

ERROR: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.itemDetails')

However, in all my other functions it seems to run fine using the same message and variables.

Just trying to place the value of the variables within the message instead of the default message: Check out this link

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To get it working, I had to change the line from

```
Branch.createBranchUniversalObject(properties).then(function (res) {
```

To

```
Branch.createBranchUniversalObject(properties).then((res) => {
```